# Filter a string from styles in php

Tags: php, javascript, css

I have  a string like this this string has some inline styles within <P><span><font> tags

> <p style='color:red; font-size:21px'><span
>   style='color:blue;'><font style='font-family:Arial'>This is
>   my string demo</font></span></p>

I want result like this

> <p><span><font>This is my string
>   demo</font></span></p>

Thanks for help

Comment: `font` is deprecated, why you want to use it?

Comment: <?php $out="This is My String demo";?>

<p><span><font><?php echo $out;?></font></span></p>

Comment: Um what exactly do you want to do?? Do you want to remove the styles you've given or provide it in an efficient manner as `<p><span><font>This is my string demo</font></span></p>`

Comment: yes sure i need like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a jQuery object from your HTML string and then use .removeAttr()  :

> var $result = $(yourHTMLString);
>
> $result.find('[style]').removeAttr('style');